# mongo hint command for native node.js driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Two same query gives me different records in mongo shell and in native node.js driver:

```
collection.find(query).limit(1).hint(hint).toArray

collection.find(query).limit(1).hint(hint).toArray
```

I supposed that in native node.js driver hint is ignored, and it was approved:

when I removed hint from query in node.js driver, the result was the same as I got when I used hint in node.js driver:

```
collection.find(query).limit(1).toArray
```

So maybe there is special rule to **use hint in node.js mongo native driver**? How to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually isn't a `.hint()` method implemented in the node driver. In order to do this you supply "options" to the cursor creation in [`.find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find):

```js
collection.find({},{ "hint": { "a": -1 }}).limit(1).toArray(function(err,docs) {
```

Providing that actually matches an index that is specified then you will get the documents returned in the selected index order. Perhaps a longer example:

```js
var async = require("async"),
    mongo = require("mongodb"),
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  async.waterfall(
    [
      function(callback) {
        db.collection('asample',function(err,collection) {
          if (err) throw err;
          callback(err,collection);
        });
      },

      function(collection,callback) {
        collection.remove(function(err,removed) {
          if (err) throw err;
          callback(err,collection);
        });
      },

      //
      function(collection,callback) {
        async.eachSeries(
          [
            { "a": 1 },
            { "a": 2 }
          ],
          function(item,callback) {
            collection.insert(item,function(err,num) {
              if (err) throw err;
              callback();
            });
          },
          function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(err,collection);
          }
        );
      },

      function(collection,callback) {
        collection.ensureIndex({ "a": -1 },function(err,index) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Index:\n%s", index);
          callback(err,collection);
        });
      },

      function(collection,callback) {
        collection.find({},{ "hint": { "a": -1 }})
          .limit(1).toArray(function(err,docs) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Docs:\n%s", JSON.stringify( docs, undefined, 4));
            callback();

        });
      }

    ],
    function(err) {
       console.log("done");
       db.close();
    }

  );

});
```

Where in the reverse index order the value of "2" is returned first.

Really though, "hint" should not need to be applied as long as either your "query" or `.sort()` specification mention the correct index to use. So that would be the better approach.